# How to do the integral part of logarthm with minimizer?

Tags: functions, computability

I have this function:

$r: N -> N $
$r(n) = \log_2(n)$

I have arrived at a version with maximization:

$r(n) = max(t) : n >= 2^t$

How do I rewrite it as a recursive function using a bounded minimization operator μ.

Comment: I have no idea what you want, but $\min(\text{something})=-max(-\text{something})$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But here $something$ is a natural, and the result $−max(−something)$ *must* be Natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $r(n)$ is the integer part of $\log_2(n)$, you can write
$$ r(n) = \min \{ t <n : n< 2^t \} -1 $$

In bounded minimization operator it is written:

$$r(n) = \mu t [(2^t\dot{-}n) + Eq(2^t, n) = 0]$$

Where Eq returns 1 when both parameters are one and zero otherwise.

Comment: Did you have a source with a proof for it?

Comment: Is the $t < n$ necessary?

Comment: No I don't have a source, but it follows the very same idea you used for writing $r(n)$ in terms of $\max$...it just goes the other way! You start high and you decrease $t$ until you find one s.t. $n \le 2^t$. Which is also why you need the $-1$: the minimization operation gives you $r(n)+1$. The $t<n$ is not necessary, that is just because in this case you have a trivial upper bound for the value of $r(n)$.